# What's a good way to write "x does not divide y"?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

The way I currently do it is `$x \not | y$`, which looks awful.  There's got to be something better available.

Comment: Did you have a look at `texdoc symbols`?

Comment: I usually prefer “x does not divide y” (at least in text). Also, have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: @Caramdir: thanks!  I knew about Detexify, but wasn't sure I could draw the symbol in the right orientation.  But Detexify finds it in the other orientation as well.  Fantastic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a ∣ b and a ∤ b in formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116580/a-%e2%88%a3-b-and-a-%e2%88%a4-b-in-formulas)

Comment: Or this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526615/algebraic-symbol-a-divide-b-or-a-non-divide-b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algebraic symbol: a divide b or a non-divide b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526615/algebraic-symbol-a-divide-b-or-a-non-divide-b)

Comment: @Sebastiano maybe it's the other way around? ;) the duplicates you propose are more recent than this question

Comment: @Sebastiano you said: "[...] but my question is different [to this one]" in the comments of your question but are marking it now as duplicate of this much older question with more votes and more different answers?

Comment: @dexteritas I really don't even remember my name nowadays. I'm tired and I come to TeX.SE occasionally to relax. What's wrong with me deleting my comment?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin With my heart in my hand...maybe I'd better go to the hospice :-( I don't understand anything. Help me to understand.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`$x\nmid y$` saves the day.

Comment: Thanks, Harald!  For some reason I thought I had tried this already.

Comment: Remember that `\nmid` is not defined in `amsmath`. `amssymb` is required for `\nmid`.

Answer (score 63):

An alternative to `\nmid` is to use the `\centernot` command from the [centernot](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/centernot.html) package. The resulting `\centernot\mid` symbol aligns perfectly with `\mid` and has a more pronounced slash than `\nmid`:

[image]

(On the right, the image shows how the commands behave in sub/superscript.)

Comment: \centernot is my favourite :)

Answer (score 29):

Another good looking (best to me) and easy option is to use the command `\notdivides` from the [`mathabx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) package. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[ \prod_{a \notdivides b}^{a \notdivides b} a \notdivides b \]
\end{document}
```

creates the output

[image: a \notdivides b]

The negating line is longer than `\nmid`'s but shorter than `\centernot`'s.

Answer (score 6):

`$x \bmod y \ne 0$` ;)

Or, as is more commonly written in mathematics: `$x \not\equiv 0 \pmod y$` or `$x \ne 0 \pmod y$`.

Comment: That's a programmer's answer. Mathematicians would probably write it $x \neq 0 (\mathrm{mod} y)$

Comment: We'd both be wrong in an algebraist's eyes because a congruence is technically in order: `$x \ncong 0 \left( \mathrm{mod} y\right)$`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The TeXnically correct way to do either of those is `$x \ncong 0 \pmod{y}` :)

Comment: To get the spacing right, the mod binary operator needs to be written as `\bmod`, not `\mod` (the latter is part of the congruence notation `a\equiv b\mod c`, which is more commonly seen with parentheses). Also, modular congruences are written with `\equiv`, not `\cong` (the latter is completely inappropriate in this context; it denotes the *geometrical* notion of congruence).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to assert, in symbols, that "a divides b" would be to use the [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) package and then use `$a \divides b$` (or `$a \ndivides b$` for doesn't divide).

As I am typing a good deal of ring theory, I'm using those all the time.