# LaTeX symbol for "does not divide"

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

What is the correct way to make the "does not divide" symbol in plain LaTeX 2e?

I'm talking about the symbol that is a vertical bar with a slash through it. I prefer not to install AMS or other packages, but instead to use plain LaTeX.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Looks similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/whats-a-good-way-to-write-x-does-not-divide-y

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

```
$x\nmid y$
```

It has been known to 'save the day'.

Comment: That doesn't work in plain LaTeX. Do you know what package must be loaded to make it work? I tried \usepackage{amsfonts} but that doesn't work. And I still prefer a plain LaTeX solution.

Comment: I got \nmid working with \usepackage{amssymb}.

Answer (score 25):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is amazingly helpful in finding any symbol.

Answer (score 7):

Using `\not` with `|` works with plain LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$2 \not| \;3 $
\end{document}
```

The symbols `\\`, and  `\:` and `\;` create varying degrees of space if the symbols get too close.

Comment: I wonder why the `\not` introduces so much space.

Comment: I'm not sure which space you're talking about but try this: $2 \!\!\not| \,3 $. The \! is negative space to get things closer together on the right and \, will reduce space on the right

Comment: Oh, I didn't think you'd come back to this! Thanks very much. I just meant that while `a|b` is nice and compact, `a\not|b` puts a strange amount of space between a and |.

Comment: I don't know why `\not` has so much extra space but if I had to guess it might be because `\not` can be used in conjunction with a lot of other symbols which are wider than | [eg \not\in or \not\subset]. So some combinations will look better than others depending on the symbol width being negated.

Comment: The spacing on `\not\mid` was ok when I used it on mathoverflow (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256598/the-exceptional-isomorphism-between-pgl3-2-and-psl2-7-geometric-origin/256600#comment632258_256598)

Comment: A relational operator intentionally has more spacing than a binary operator (since normally we group the terms of binary operators on the same side of a relation). You can change the spacing to that of a binary operator by wrapping the symbol in `\mathbin`, or even typeset it as an ordinary letter using `\mathord`.

Answer (score 5):

To minimize used packages you can do this:

`\newcommand{\ndiv}{\hspace{-4pt}\not|\hspace{2pt}}`

From then on `\ndiv` will add the sign with appropriate spaces before and after.

Comment: If the font size changes, this can cause a lot of headache. At least you can opt for units like `ex,em` but still it would not be robust enough to be used elsewhere.

Comment: @percusse: can you provide a more robust way?

Comment: @cxxl The answers above are pretty good. Otherwise you can look for the definitions from the LaTeX versions and carry them to plain TeX as raw macros.

Answer (score 5):

The ∤ symbol is available in Unicode as U+2224 Does Not Divide, and as `\nmid` from many packages, including: `unicode-math`, `amssymb`, `stix`, `stix2`, `newtxmath` and the less commonly-used`mnsymbol`, `fdsymbol` and `boisk`.

Answer (score 0):

After fine tuning, I'm pretty happy with defining a new command `\doesnotdivide` (or whatever you'd like to name it) as: `\newcommand{\doesnotdivide}{\not\hspace{2.5pt}\mid}`

I found that three points was too much and 2 points was not enough offset.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to blerbl's answer.  Note that a comment there points out that measuring in `em` would be better than `pt`, since it would automatically adjust to a change in font size.