# Algebraic symbol: a divide b or a non-divide b

Tags: symbols, packages

I refer to my period when I was in University. I think that the usual symbols for writing that `a` divide `b` or that `a` not divide `b` are those of this compilable example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[a\mid b, \quad a\nmid b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I remember that the vertical bar was drawn longer and with smaller letters like this drawing, all in proportion, of course.

[image]

Are there specific packages with `LaTeX` that automatically create this type of approach different from the standard one?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/whats-a-good-way-to-write-x-does-not-divide-y

Comment: @jsbibra Thank you for your reply but my question is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with package `leftidx` and, dor the negated version, `stackinset` from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{stackengine, graphicx}
\newcommand{\divides}[2]{\leftidx{^{#1}}{\Big\vert}{_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\ndivides}[2]{\leftidx{^{#1}}{\nBigvert}{_{#2}}}

 \newcommand{\nBigvert}{\stackMath\mathord{\stackinset{l}{0.15ex}{c}{0ex}{\rotatebox{45}{$\relbar $}}{\Big\vert}}}

\begin{document}

$\divides{\mathsf{a}\mkern-1.5mu}{\mathsf{b}}\quad \ndivides{\mathsf{b}\mkern-1.5mu}{\mathsf{a}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]